# jQuery scrollTop - no support for negative values in Mozilla / Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, scrolltop

Just wondering if anyone has been able to work around Firefox / Mozilla not having support for negative `scrollTop` values.

Chrome and Safari (WebKit) both seem to be able to allow the user to scroll past page content and return a negative value when using `scrollTop` in jQuery. Although when using on Firefox it is not possible to scroll past the content and receive negative `scrollTop` values.

Anyone else having the same problem?

Thanks,
David

Comment: AFAIK scrollTop is already the positive N of the element  'negative' top scroll position...

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 10)`?

Answer (score 1):

As scrollTop's default behaviour scrolls to 0 when passing a negative value, I did this function that handles scrollTop and simulate a "scrollDown".

If *anchor_pos* is negative (so it's above my current scroll position), I subtract its value from current scroll position (as it has a negative value, I'm using + sign)

```
function jumpToAnchor(scrollable_div_selector, anchor_selector)
{
    anchor_pos = $(anchor_selector).position().top;

    //check if negative value
    if (anchor_pos < 0)
    {
        anchor_pos = $(scrollable_div_selector).scrollTop() + anchor_pos; //anchor_pos is negative, so i'm substracting it
    }

    $(scrollable_div_selector).scrollTop(anchor_pos);
}
```